# Issue using @Input in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm working on my first angular project and my home component html looks like below

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1 id="tableLabel">Latest</h1>
      <news-item [section]="Latest"></news-item>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1 id="tableLabel">STEM Stuff</h1>
      <news-item [section]="STEM"></news-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the ts for news-item is as below

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'news-item',
    templateUrl: './news-item.component.html',
})

export class NewsItemComponent {

    public newsitems: NewsItem[];

    @Input() section: string;

    constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

            http.get<NewsItem[]>(baseUrl + 'newsitems/GetNewsItemsBySection/' + this.section).subscribe(result => {

                this.newsitems = result;

            }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

I'm getting `this.section` as `undefined` within the constructor. What am I missing ?

Comment: why have you mapped `section` as `@Input`? are you passing some information from `<news-item>` to the controller? At first instance `<news-item>` looks like for rendering purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in within `ngOnInit()` or `ngOnChanges()`

The difference between constructor and `ngOnInit` is that `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook runs after constructor. Input initial values aren't available in constructor, but they are available in `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

The code in constructor executes before the component receives the changes, you need to shift the logic to `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 0):

`<news-item [section]="STEM"></news-item>`

Angular will interpolate this as value of STEM, and STEM is not defined home component. so the section in news-item component is undefined

`<news-item section="STEM"></news-item>`

This will interpolate as STEM as a string not an variable.

I hope this will work for you.

````
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1 id="tableLabel">Latest</h1>
      <news-item section="Latest"></news-item>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1 id="tableLabel">STEM Stuff</h1>
      <news-item section="STEM"></news-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```
````